# NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I am getting an error when using a custom wrapper for MSAL 2.0

Here is the wrapper ts file

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, InjectionToken, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LogLevel, Configuration, BrowserCacheLocation, InteractionType, IPublicClientApplication, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { ConfigService } from './shared/services/config.service';
import jsonconfig from '../assets/environment/conf.json'
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MsalBroadcastService, MsalGuard, MsalGuardConfiguration, MsalInterceptor, MsalInterceptorConfiguration, MsalModule, MsalService, MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG, MSAL_INSTANCE, MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG } from '@azure/msal-angular';
 const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;
 
 const AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('AUTH_CONFIG_URL');

 export function initializerFactory(env: ConfigService): any {
     // APP_INITIALIZER, except a function return which will return a promise
     // APP_INITIALIZER, angular doesnt starts application untill it completes
     const promise = env.init().then((value) => {
         console.log(env.getSettings('clientID'));
     });
     return () => promise;
 }


 
 export function MSALInstanceFactory(conf:ConfigService): IPublicClientApplication {
     const configuration:Configuration={
     auth: {
         clientId: conf.getSettings("clientId"), // This is the ONLY mandatory field that you need to supply.
         authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+ conf.getSettings("tenentId"), // Defaults to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
         redirectUri: conf.getSettings("redirectUri"), // Points to window.location.origin. You must register this URI on Azure portal/App Registration.
         postLogoutRedirectUri: '/', // Indicates the page to navigate after logout.
         navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true, // If "true", will navigate back to the original request location before processing the auth code response.
     },
     cache: {
         cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage, // Configures cache location. "sessionStorage" is more secure, but "localStorage" gives you SSO between tabs.
         storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
     },
     system: {
         loggerOptions: {
             loggerCallback(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {
                 console.log(message);
             },
             logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose,
             piiLoggingEnabled: false
         }
     }
    }
    return new PublicClientApplication(configuration);
 }

 
 export const silentRequest = {
     scopes: ["openid", "profile"],
     loginHint: "example@domain.net"
 };

 
export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: []
  };

  export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(conf:ConfigService): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
    const protectedResources:Map<string, Array<string>>=new Map([
        ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']],
        [
          'api',
          [conf.getSettings("apiClientId") + '/user_impersonation'],
        ],
      ]);
    
    return {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      protectedResourceMap: protectedResources
    };
  }
  
  export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
    return { 
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: loginRequest
    };
  }
//-------------------------------------------------------------
@NgModule({
    providers: [
    ],
    imports: [MsalModule]
})
export class MsalConfModule{
    staticforroot() {
        return {
            providers: [
                { provide: AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN },
                { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializerFactory,
                    deps: [ConfigService, 
                    AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN], 
                    multi: true 
                },
                {
                  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                  useClass: MsalInterceptor,
                  multi: true,
                  
                },
                {
                  provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
                  useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory,
                  deps: [ConfigService]
                },
                {
                  provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
                  useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
                },
                {
                  provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
                  useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory,
                  deps: [ConfigService]
                },
                MsalService,
                MsalGuard,
                MsalBroadcastService
            ],
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the app module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule,AppRoutingComonent } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http'

import { MsalConfModule } from './authconfig';


const ngWizardConfig: NgWizardConfig = {
  theme: THEME.default
};


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppRoutingComonent,
  
  
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DataTablesModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, // required animations module
    ToastrModule.forRoot(), // ToastrModule added,
    NgWizardModule.forRoot(ngWizardConfig),
    MsalConfModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
    provide: MatDialogRef,
    useValue: {}
    }
],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
  
}
```

There is no compile error. I am getting a run time error below
[image]

Based on J.Loscos answer I have updated the code, but now this error shows

```
Type '{ provide: InjectionToken<string>; }' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
  Type '{ provide: InjectionToken<string>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Type<any>'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you declare the injection tokens in the staticforroot method but you don't use this method.

It seems that you are trying to use the forRoot pattern for module import.
To use this pattern, your staticforroot method in the module should return the module in addition of the providers :

```js
@NgModule({
    providers: [
    ],
    imports: [MsalModule]
})
export class MsalConfModule{
    staticforroot() : ModuleWithProviders<MsalConfModule>  {
        return {
            ngModule: MsalConfModule,
            providers: [
                { provide: AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN },
                { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializerFactory,
                    deps: [ConfigService, 
                    AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN], 
                    multi: true 
                },
                ...
           ]
        };
     }
```

And when importing this module in your AppModule you need to call the staticforroot method :

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppRoutingComonent,
  
  
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
    MsalConfModule.staticforroot()
  ],
  providers: [
    {
    provide: MatDialogRef,
    useValue: {}
    }
],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that suggestion. But I tried that and getting this error now
Type '{ provide: InjectionToken<string>; }' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
  Type '{ provide: InjectionToken<string>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Type<any>'. Will update the question with this details as well

Comment: I think this error comes from the ` { provide: AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN }` because it doesn't have a `use`, `useClass` or `useFactory`

Comment: Could you please suggest what I can mention there.. :(

Comment: Based on the name of the injection token, I imagine it's intended to be the url of a config file. So you could do something like `{ provide: AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN, use: "https://yourbackend/config.json" }`
But I see that you declare this token as a dependency of the initializerFactory, but this factory doesn't use it. So if it's not used anywhere else you can also remove the provider and remove it from the initializerFactory dependencies

Comment: Thanks a lot friend.. I deleted that provider. Now its Property 'ngModule' is missing in type '{ providers: ({ provide: InjectionToken<(() => void)[]>; useFactory: (env: ConfigService) => any; deps: (typeof ConfigService)[]; multi: true; } | { provide: InjectionToken<...>; useClass: typeof MsalInterceptor; multi: true; } | ... 5 more ... | typeof MsalBroadcastService)[]; }' but required in type 'ModuleWithProviders<MsalConfModule>'.ts(2741)
core.d.ts(4279, 5): 'ngModule' is declared here.

Comment: In my answer I added a property ngModule to the object returned by the staticforroot method. Did you include it in your code?

Comment: I owe to you my life bro.. You are a life saver.. Love you..