# App Module Provider throws NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory

I have configuration wrapper like this for Azure AD authenticaton

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, InjectionToken, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LogLevel, Configuration, BrowserCacheLocation, InteractionType, IPublicClientApplication, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { ConfigService } from './shared/services/config.service';
import jsonconfig from '../assets/environment/conf.json'
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MsalBroadcastService, MsalGuard, MsalGuardConfiguration, MsalInterceptor, MsalInterceptorConfiguration, MsalModule, MsalService, MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG, MSAL_INSTANCE, MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG } from '@azure/msal-angular';
 const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;
 
 const AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('AUTH_CONFIG_URL');

 export function initializerFactory(env: ConfigService): any {
     // APP_INITIALIZER, except a function return which will return a promise
     // APP_INITIALIZER, angular doesnt starts application untill it completes
     const promise = env.init().then((value) => {
         console.log(env.getSettings('clientID'));
     });
     return () => promise;
 }



 export function MSALInstanceFactory(conf:ConfigService): IPublicClientApplication {
     const configuration:Configuration={
     auth: {
         clientId: conf.getSettings("clientId"), // This is the ONLY mandatory field that you need to supply.
         authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+ conf.getSettings("tenentId"), // Defaults to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
         redirectUri: conf.getSettings("redirectUri"), // Points to window.location.origin. You must register this URI on Azure portal/App Registration.
         postLogoutRedirectUri: '/', // Indicates the page to navigate after logout.
         navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true, // If "true", will navigate back to the original request location before processing the auth code response.
     },
     cache: {
         cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage, // Configures cache location. "sessionStorage" is more secure, but "localStorage" gives you SSO between tabs.
         storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
     },
     system: {
         loggerOptions: {
             loggerCallback(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {
                 console.log(message);
             },
             logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose,
             piiLoggingEnabled: false
         }
     }
    }
    return new PublicClientApplication(configuration);
 }


 export const silentRequest = {
     scopes: ["openid", "profile"],
     loginHint: "example@domain.net"
 };


export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: []
  };

export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(conf:ConfigService): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
    const protectedResources:Map<string, Array<string>>=new Map([
        ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']],
        [
          'api',
          [conf.getSettings("apiClientId") + '/user_impersonation'],
        ],
      ]);
    
    return {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      protectedResourceMap: protectedResources
    };
  }
  
export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
    const auth= { 
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: loginRequest
    };
    return(auth as MsalGuardConfiguration)
  }
//-------------------------------------------------------------
@NgModule({
    providers: [
    ],
    imports: [MsalModule]
})
export class MsalConfModule{
    static forRoot() {
        return {
            providers: [
                { provide: AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN },
                { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializerFactory,
                    deps: [ConfigService, 
                    AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN], 
                    multi: true 
                },
                {
                  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                  useClass: MsalInterceptor,
                  multi: true,
                  
                },
                {
                  provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
                  useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory,
                  deps: [ConfigService]
                },
                {
                  provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
                  useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
                },
                {
                  provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
                  useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory,
                  deps: [ConfigService]
                },
                MsalService,
                MsalGuard,
                MsalBroadcastService
            ],
        }
    }

}
```

And I am trying to use that wrapper in App Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule,AppRoutingComonent } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http'
import { MsalConfModule } from './authconfig';


const ngWizardConfig: NgWizardConfig = {
  theme: THEME.default
};


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppRoutingComonent,
  
  
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

    AppRoutingModule,

    MsalConfModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
    provide: MatDialogRef,
    useValue: {}
    }
],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
  
}
```

But there was not error at compile time. I am getting runtime error saying

> main.ts:12 NullInjectorError:
> R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG ->
> InjectionToken MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG -> InjectionToken MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG!

[image]

I didnt understand what I did wrong. Please help

Based on the answer by Brian, I have tried adding forRoot like this in app module

```
MsalConfModule.forRoot()
```

But that triggered a compile error

```
Type '{ providers: (typeof MsalService | typeof MsalGuard | typeof MsalBroadcastService | { provide: InjectionToken<string>; useFactory?: undefined; deps?: undefined; multi?: undefined; useClass?: undefined; } | ... 4 more ... | { ...; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.
  Property 'ngModule' is missing in type '{ providers: (typeof MsalService | typeof MsalGuard | typeof MsalBroadcastService | { provide: InjectionToken<string>; useFactory?: undefined; deps?: undefined; multi?: undefined; useClass?: undefined; } | ... 4 more ... | { ...; })[]; }' but required in type 'ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.ts(2322)
core.d.ts(4279, 5): 'ngModule' is declared here.
```

I missed to mention, my angular version 11.0

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MSAL\_GUARD\_CONFIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68132252/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-injectiontoken-msal-guard-config)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `forRoot()` in your app.module.ts to MsalConfModule since you have a module with providers.

app.module.ts

```
MsalConfModule.forRoot()
```

Update your `forRoot()` with the following:

```
export class MsalConfModule{
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<MsalConfModule> {
      return {
        ngModule: MsalConfModule,
          providers: [
              { provide: AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN },
              { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializerFactory,
                  deps: [ConfigService, 
                  AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN], 
                  multi: true 
              },
              {
                provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                useClass: MsalInterceptor,
                multi: true,
                
              },
              {
                provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
                useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory,
                deps: [ConfigService]
              },
              {
                provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
                useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
              },
              {
                provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
                useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory,
                deps: [ConfigService]
              },
              MsalService,
              MsalGuard,
              MsalBroadcastService
          ],
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry friend.. I just tried that, but doesnt work. Still the same error

Comment: Updated my answer with another thing to try

Comment: That's triggering a compile error which is little lengthy, so I am updating my question with that

Comment: Just updated my question after trying the point you have mentioned.